# Edge of Worksheet in Excel Wrapping Around

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm experiencing an inconvenience on an Excel project- whenever I go to cell A1 and go up or left, instead of stopping, the sheet goes to the most extreme cell with info on it (I had hid some numbers in the row 12000 to get them out of the way). This happens whenever I go left from column 1, right from column BF, up from row 1, or down from row 12000. (My extreme-most data is in row 12000, column BF). Is there any way to prevent the sheet from wrapping like this? Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason you entered them in row 12000 instead of just hiding the row?

Comment: Good point haha; I suppose I could change that.  Regardless, though, any idea on what or why the problem described above is happening or how to change it?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013

Comment: if you click ctrl-end does it take you to the same cell?

Comment: Just a thought here. Something that happened to me years ago and it had me stumped. Is it possible you are in Split View or any Freeze Payne view? I did that once and forgot the split was there and it ran me raging. It might be possible that you inadvertently put a Freeze Payne there. View, Unfreeze Paynes.